# Multidimensional array detect when something is sealed off

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I'm messing around a bit with Javascript making a small 2D grid-based game and I now want my application to be able to tell when someone has made a room(aka when an area is completely sealed off from the outside), but I can't seem to figure out how to tackle this issue in an efficient way.

Currently you can place walls on a tile which then get added in the corresponding spot in the two dimensional array, but it's also possible to add other types of buildings that should be ignored in this use case. I guess I could achieve this in some way by using a pathfinding library but any thoughts on how to efficiently accomplish this would be greatly appreciated!

Dumbed down example of what such an array might look like:

```
[][][][{type: wall}, {type: 'not a wall'}][][][]
[][][][{type: wall}][{type: wall}][][]
[][][][][][][]
[][][][][][][]
```

Comment: you're asking this question as if everyone here is already familiar with your app. i have no idea what "made a room" means or what it means to "seal off an area" ...best guess is you're rebuilding minecraft?? either way, you need to show more code.

Comment: The simplest approach might be to [flood the room](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floodfill) which basically is a breadth-first search for the [connected component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)) in the graph of floor tiles. Alternatively, take your walls as nodes of a graph (connected if adjacent to each other) and try to [find cycles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection_(graph_theory)) therein.

Comment: I think I've explained all that is needed to know, extra information would just get in the way of the question. I'm just looking for an efficient way to detect sealed off areas in a multidimensional array.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The flood the room method was something I had in mind as well. I guess that can be somewhat easily achieved by a pathfinding library? I don't really grasp the cycles method.